# Can I check if class implements an interface when it is casted to other interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting

Is it possible to check interface implementation in this way?

```
class ProjectSettingsApplier : ISettingsApplier, IApplyChanges
{
}


ISettingsApplier applier = new ProjectSettingsApplier()
if(applier is IApplyChanges)
{
    //Is it true??
}
```

Comment: What your compiler says about this??? (= you need less time to try by yourself than to ask).

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation for `is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/scekt9xw.aspx):

> An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is
>   non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type
>   without causing an exception to be thrown. Otherwise, the expression
>   evaluates to false.

So I would say yes, that would work.

That said, a simple repro would likely answer this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is valid, and looks like a good way to do the check.

If all `IApplyChanges` are also `ISettingsApplier`s, you should make `IApplyChanges : ISettingsApplier`, to make the relationship clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is legal since `applier` is in fact implementing `IApplyChanges`. In your case, it will the evaluation will be `true`.

Alternatively, you can use `IsAssignableFrom` but it's way more chatty and you have to make sure applier is not `null`:

```
typeof(IApplyChanges).IsAssignableFrom(applier.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly OK, but if you want to go on to cast the interface to `IApplyChanges` to use it, you should use `as` instead of `is` like so:

```
ISettingsApplier applier = new ProjectSettingsApplier()

var changer = applier as IApplyChanges;

if (changer != null) // Will only be non-null if it implements IApplyChanges
{
    // Use changer.
}
```

Doing it this way avoids a double type check, which is not as efficient. In other words, *don't* do it like this:

```
ISettingsApplier applier = new ProjectSettingsApplier()

if (applier is IApplyChanges) // Type check #1
{
    var changer = (IApplyChanges) applier; // Type check #2: Inefficient.
    // Use changer.
}
```